# What's the difference between “client” and “user”?

Tags: word-usage

I want to know the difference between *client* and *user*.  When should we use client, and when we should use user?

Comment: Practically a duplicate of: [What's the difference between “client” and “customer”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15187/whats-the-difference-between-client-and-customer?rq=1) Have you tried looking up the definitions in... an online dictionary? What did they say?

Comment: It is impossible to say definitively without additional context. The OED identifies no fewer than eight distinct uses of *client*, for example.

Comment: Not quite, @Mari-LouA.  A 'user' is different than a client or customer in terms of control or authority and handling requests from users may be different than responses to the decision-making 'client', at least in the realm of IT support.

Comment: @KristinaLopez - Truth. In the unspoken/unwritten IT handbook, you have to be nice to a "client." "Users" are an unfortunate obstacle between goals and operational nirvana.

Comment: Ha! @Rob_Ster!  Users are usually my best source for what the "client" *really* needs but they have no real influence since they don't directly pay the bills for our software.

Comment: @KristinaLopez - When I did education IT, users were the main reason great applications didn't work right. If only one could design them out...

Answer (score 2):

There are two broad answers.

Sometimes a client refers to a business partner, customer, or anyone who has a direct dealing with your company.

Sometimes a client refers to a program connected to your system. This type of client may be a browser, native app, command-line tool, etc. The user is typically the person using that client, but may generically refer to a person or program that persists its identity between usage sessions.

Business relationship example:  My client can't log in to the system.

Program example:  His web client is having trouble connecting.